# Why was this question closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I asked [this](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3899/home-page-design-with-search-options) question ages ago and I received some answers as well. I just want to understand why it was closed as not a real question. it is clearly a question about how a search page is designed and what can make it complicated.

Comment: I can't speak for Ben, but your question is highly dependent on context and the details of the project. It's not really a question anyone can answer without being fully entrenched in the project and understanding the users, business objectives, the visual design, etc.